# How to validate files with FluentValidation

Tags: c#, asp.net, fluentvalidation, iformfile

I want to check with FluentValidation if the file I received with IFormFile has the image extension. How can I do that?

Comment: Create a Rule for the [FileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile.filename?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-iformfile-filename) property.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
public class FormFileValidator : AbstractValidator<IFormFile>
{
    public FormFileValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.FileName).Must(a =>a.EndsWith(".png")) // put your logic based on extension you want.
            .WithMessage("Given file is not a image type");
    }
}
```

and then in your controller you can validate file like this.

```
var result = new FormFileValidator().Validate(file);
```

Comment: That's how I did it, but it doesn't go inside the Validate method.

Comment: you have to write the code for calling validation in your controller like I put in my example. it will not automatically validate.

Comment: I wrote it but it doesn't work. If you want, you can connect to my computer with 'anydesk' connection.

Comment: how are you adding fluentvalidation in your startup/program file. and also add your controller api definition

Comment: protected override void OnBefore(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            var validator = (IValidator)Activator.CreateInstance(_validatorType)!;
            var entityType = _validatorType.BaseType?.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            var entities = invocation.Arguments.Where(t => t.GetType() == entityType); 

            foreach (var entity in entities)
            {
                ValidationTool.Validate(validator, entity);
            }
        }

Comment: [HttpPost("add")]
        public IActionResult Add([FromForm(Name = "Image")] IFormFile file, [FromForm] CarImage carImage)
        {
            var result = _carImageService.Add(file, carImage);

            if (result.Success)
            {
                return Ok(result);
            }

            return BadRequest(result);
        }

Comment: why do you need the OnBefore logic, you can simply use `new FormFileValidator().Validate(file);` this line and do the validation inside controller itself.

Comment: Because I may need to use validation aspects everywhere, so I made validation a tool and used the OnBefore method to be able to call it at the beginning of the method.

Comment: The problem is not the method anyway. The problem is that IFormFile does not match the type of file taken as a parameter.